# error while initializing window.navigator.getUserMedia in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm trying to use window.navigator.getUserMedia in my code & it's showing me weird long error.

Here is my code:

```
 window.navigator.getUserMedia(audio: true, video: true).then((stream) {
      _localRenderer.srcObject = stream;
});
```

error :

```
A value of type 'MediaStream (where MediaStream is defined in /home/klaus/developement/flutter/bin/cache/pkg/sky_engine/lib/html/html_dart2js.dart)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'MediaStream (where MediaStream is defined in /home/klaus/developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.3.2/lib/src/media_stream.dart)'.
Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'MediaStream (where MediaStream is defined in /home/klaus/developement/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_webrtc-0.3.2/lib/src/media_stream.dart)'
```

Answer (score -1):

Use    MediaDevices    instead of navigator
like this

```
MediaDevices.getUserMedia(constrains).then((MediaStream stream) {
  _localRenderer.srcObject = stream;
}
```